# Camunda - Oracle Database 19c UTF-8 encoding

Tags: oracle, camunda

i am currently using Oracle Database 19c with UTF-8 encoding.

From my application i use the REST Engine to deploy my processes.

Sadly letters like “ä” are saved as “Ã¤” in my database.

I already tried to add `SET JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to my `start.bat` file but no success.

Also if i add

```yaml
spring.datasource:
   url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//myhost:1522/myorcldbservicename?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

to the `default.yml` brings no success.
I no longer know what to do… maybe someone of you can help.

My default.yml:

```yaml
camunda.bpm:
  database:
    type: oracle
    jdbc-batch-processing: false
    schema-update: false
  admin-user:
    id: demo
    password: demo
  run:

    cors:
      enabled: true
      allowed-origins: "*"

spring.datasource:
  url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//myhost:1522/myorcldbservicename?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
  driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

  username: CAMUNDA
  password: 123

spring.web.resources:
  static-locations: NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution on my own.
The clou is not to add `SET JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to the `start.bat` but adding the `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to `call %JAVA%` in the `start.bat` like so:

```sh
call %JAVA% -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 ...
```